# Stripe - Submit token/create charge through 1 HTML-button?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, stripe-payments

```
                    <!-- Stripeform -->
                    <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="card-element">
                            Credit or debit card
                            </label>
                            <div id="card-element">
                            <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                            </div>

                            <!-- Used to display form errors -->
                            <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                        </div>

                        <button>Submit Payment</button>
                    </form>
```

This HTML-code, together with my `controller.js` is able to submit a token to [Stripe](https://stripe.com/). I also have a `server.js` written in `Node.js`, that successfully charges to Stripe:

```
// Get our dependencies
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_111111111111111111111111");
var express = require('express'), bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
var app = express();
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var rsaValidation = require('auth0-api-jwt-rsa-validation');

//Implement charge endpoint 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
// for kicks, just sending checkout
res.send('<form action="/charge" method="POST">Buy it !<script 
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" data-
key="pk_test_111111111111111111111"></script></form>')
});

app.post('/charge',urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {

//grab a token
var token = req.body.stripeToken;

//Creating a charge
stripe.charges.create({
amount: 2000,
currency: "usd",
source: token, // obtained with Stripe.js
description: "Charge"
}, function(err, charge) {
    res.send("You made a charge: "+ charge.id);
});
}); 

app.listen(5000)
```

Problem is, they work independently. If I localhost my website folder `public` (which also has the `server.js` located in `public/subfolder`) at port `7878`, the Submit payment-button successfully submits a token with the Stripe test card info, but then redirects me to `file:///D:/charge`, with a `404`-error.

 Now if I run `node server.js` in cmd, and go to `localhost:5000`, then I can make a charge with the test card.

I want the button **on my website** to generate, and submit token (which it does), AND initiate the charge.

Feel free to elaborate on the API/HTML relationship, as I'm obviously confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're serving the files up directly, you're not actually running a Node server, so there's no way for the `/charge` route to run.

In order for this to work, you'll need the server side Node code to run on a server - and be accessible to the HTML file for the `<form>` submission; that stuff can't be run client side - so you'll need to host that somewhere.

It doesn't necessarily need to be hosted the same place as the HTML, but it does need to be accessible from the web *somewhere*.

You might want to look at something like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/nodejs) for hosting that part.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. However, I have tried deploying everything at firebase, and hosting it online from there, but 404 still occurs. Is hosting the node server a different process than hosting the rest of the website? Have I just uploaded the file(s), without it actually 'running'? Is the firebase free plan or platform itself hindering me? Thanks again

Comment: You could use Firebase's Cloud Functions for this, but they work differently than a 'regular Node Express app': https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: I will look into the Cloud Functions. If I want to use a regular Node Express app tho, and host it at something like Heroku, I would also have to host my front-end somewhere else than Firebase, correct? Do you got a personal recommendation which setup is the best for a startup business?